# Delay between app process start and Application onCreate

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, cold-start

I'm working on an application with large codebase.
The problem is that when I launch the app from cold start state, It takes a lot of time to show the first screen of the app. 
Based on [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#time-initial) I checked the **TTID** for the app and it was terrifying:

```
Displayed com.example.myapp/.ui.MainActivity: +6s501ms
```

So I put some logs to check where is the problem:

```kotlin
class MyApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.d("Performance", "MyApp::onCreate::start")
        super.onCreate()
        // App initializations
        Log.d("Performance", "MyApp::onCreate::end")
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("Performance", "MainActivity::onCreate::start")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Ui initializations
        Log.d("Performance", "MainActivity::onCreate::end")
    }
}
```

After this I realized something strange:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (4572) for package com.example.myapp ----------------------------
13:58:06.819 Performance    D  MyApp::onCreate::start
13:58:07.066 Performance    D  MyApp::onCreate::end
13:58:07.132 Performance    D  MainActivity::onCreate::start
13:58:07.566 Performance    D  MainActivity::onCreate::end
```

I noticed a strange thing. That there is a lot of delay (about 5 seconds) between `PROCESS_START` and `App:onCreate` (there isn't any timestamp for `PROCESS_START` but I calculated manually). Also app creation and activity creation does not take more than **1** second. 
So how can I solve this problem? What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Is this a debug build? Are you in debug mode instead of run mode? I think either of these can introduce slowness.

Comment: You may have 1+ libraries registering `ContentObservers` that do work when the process is started.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes this logs belong to the debug build but its not in debug mode.
Also I've to mention that I started to check the performance due to reports of usages with release build

Comment: If you have a customized Application class that do heavy processing, that could be a reason

Comment: You added a bounty, but have you looked into the Content Observers yet, as mentioned in the comment above? That's a likely culprit.

Comment: @Tenfour04
I looked up and found 5 libs that were using ContentObserver. I removed 3 of them for testing purpose but couldn't remove 2 of them since they are being used everywhere (room and compose). but the results are still the same.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to remove them but still same issue

Comment: @Zain I've commented most of them and used lazyLoading to test if the application is the problem but its not.

Comment: Is it possible that you have too many dependencies which all need to be loaded before `onCreate` can be called? This could happen for example if you have static initializer or call functions on `MyApp` field initializers, and maybe if you have third party library types declared as `MyApp` fields, because the classes might be loaded when `MyApp` is loaded.

Comment: Also, rather than `Log.d` profile your app as shown in the page you linked: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#bottlenecks